# create a windows service in C# that would listen/monitor MS outlook, read incoming emails and logs all the information

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to integrate MS outlook with selenium web driver using C-sharp. I want to read incoming emails, fetch all elements in it like text, images, URL and will be logging these details so that it can be retrieved later. Ideally I want to create a windows service which would continuously listen/monitor outlook and then reading all incoming emails.

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: You can use Mail.dll - .NET email component (IMAP, POP3, SMTP) nuget

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automate Outlook (or any Office application) from a Windows service application.  The reason is that MS Outlook requires a logged on user and a user session, while Windows Server apps run without a user session.

What you should do is integrate with Exchange.  Create a Windows service app that monitors new e-mails from Exchange.  See examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations).

Comment: This is the code I am using to read unread emails coming in MS outlook: